# Match sequence many times

Tags: python, regex

I wish to match a group many times.

```
import re
re.findall(r'\\x\w{2}',"echo -e '\\x6b\\x61\\x6d\\x69' random \\x6b\\x61")
>> ['\\x6b', '\\x61', '\\x6d', '\\x69', '\\x6b', '\\x61']
```

which gives me the expected result of an array. However,

```
re.findall(r'(\\x\w{2})+',"echo -e '\\x6b\\x61\\x6d\\x69' random \\x6b\\x61")
>> ['\\x69', '\\x61']
```

i.e. the last match of each set of hexadecimal numbers. I assumed that having the `+` would match the group atleast once, but this is clearly not the case. I was hoping this would have given me `['\\x6b\\x61\\x6d\\x69','\\x6b\\x61']`.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a non-capture group of `\\x\w{2}` with `?:` so as to repeat the pattern with `+` and then capture the *multiplied* pattern, `((?:\\x\w{2})+)` should capture one or more continuous pattern as `\\x\w{2}`:

```
re.findall(r'((?:\\x\w{2})+)',"echo -e '\\x6b\\x61\\x6d\\x69' random \\x6b\\x61")

# ['\\x6b\\x61\\x6d\\x69', '\\x6b\\x61']
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. This whole none capture groups, is it so that it focuses on the outer paranthesis as the capturing group?

Comment: The non-capture group is for the purpose of `+` being applied to the whole pattern instead of the character directly before it. And since you just want to capture the outer pattern, you need to make the inner group *non-capture*.

Answer (score 1):

Because `+` not in the group.

```
>>> re.findall(r'((\\x\w{2})+)',"echo -e '\\x6b\\x61\\x6d\\x69' random \\x6b\\x61")
[('\\x6b\\x61\\x6d\\x69', '\\x69'), ('\\x6b\\x61', '\\x61')]
```

You can use a non-capturing version of regular parentheses.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\\x\w{2})+',"echo -e '\\x6b\\x61\\x6d\\x69' random \\x6b\\x61")
['\\x6b\\x61\\x6d\\x69', '\\x6b\\x61']
```